# Can attribute id="" in a tag cause any troubles?

Tags: html, dom

Found set by other developers attribute `id=""` for several tags. Can it cause any troubles in any browser?

Comment: Why are you asking that question?

Comment: i dont see any problems in chrome, but not so sure about other browsers/versions

Comment: @Purag i meant the several id's are set as empty strings

Comment: wow, my apologies. I guess I need to get some sleep. :)